# What happens if Android device does not have GPS as a location provider

Tags: android, gps, location, settings, listener

Given this code

```
if (!locator.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


        //consider forcing user to turn on gps here
    } else {

        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    }
```

What happens if the device does not have GPS. Right now if that provider isn't enabled then it I will jump the user to their system settings to turn it on. But what if it isn't there? How would this be handled. I dont want to necessarily lock those kind of users out of the app.

Comment: Have you written a test to see for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the GPS provider is not available (or enabled), then try for whatever you can get:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

This assumes that you prefer a rough position over no position at all.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the GPS if you want precise locations.  If the device simply does not have a GPS, then you can estimate with less accuracy through the NETWORK_PROVIDER.  That's usually suitable if you just need the general location of a user (west side of a city, near a memorial, etc.).  If you absolutely need a specific location that's within a specific accuracy for your app to work, then you're user without GPS is just out of luck.

Alternatively, if you enable GPS and the user doesn't have GPS, it simply won't get updates.  In that case, you'll have to mention that the updates aren't precise because of lack of GPS, and the user will have to use a weaker version of your app.